# What does "legit LOL" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

The context (in a chat):

```
- Person1 says something
- Person2 responds with an animated GIF
- Person3 says "legit LOL to Person2's reaction!"
```

What does "legit LOL" mean?
Does Person3 want to stress that he genuinely loughs looking at the GIF and not auto-responding with "LOL"?

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legit#:~:text=adverb,actually%20%E2%80%94used%20for%20emphasis%20%22%E2%80%A6) Definition of **legit** (Entry 2 of 2)
***slang***
: REALLY, ACTUALLY —used for emphasis
*"… I got a lot going on, and I don't remember things very well, and I forgot. I legit forgot."* — Kristen Bell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LOL is an abbreviation for 'laughing out loud'. Initially used to express actual laughter, which obviously could not be heard in an email or text message, it is now generally considered to have become so overused that it does not mean the person using it is actually, literally laughing out loud and is no more than a token acknowledgement that something funny has been said. This has lead to some people clarifying that they genuinely mean it by saying something like "*actually LOL*".

"Legit" is an abbreviation of "legitimately", which can mean 'actually' or 'really'. So it would seem "*legit LOL*" means someone is really, genuinely laughing out loud.